# Change label on change DropDownListFor value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html.dropdownlistfor

I use a `DropDownListFor` and a label text on my page.

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MotiveClientType,
                        new SelectList(
                            Model.ClientMotives, "Id", "Label", Model.MotiveClientType),
                        new { id = "ddlMotiveClientType" }
)%>
```

How can I change my label when selecting value on my `DropDownListFor`?

Comment: you mean you want to change the dropdown label onclick ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any functionality native to ASP.NET MVC that will allow you to do this, but doing it with jQuery is a fairly trivial matter. Here's an example of hooking up an event handler to the change event of the dropdown & then setting the label text:

```
$("#DropDownID").change(function () {
    $("#LabelID").text("Your text here");
});
```

Just replace the IDs with the relevant values.